# Does D2L have a way for the instructor to access my submission while it appears "unread"?

Tags: professorship, grading

My school uses D2L for all classes. When I submit a paper (or other file) to D2L, I can see in the "Dropbox" whether or not the professor has read a submitted file. In most of my courses, I see the indicator change from "unread" to "read" and then I see the grade posted.

I have one course where I've been receiving grades without every assignment being changed to "read". This course is led by a professor who is... I'll say, less than enthusiastic about the course.

While this is a general education course for which I'm not expecting any significant feedback on my work, I am concerned that this professor is forsaking grading assignments altogether and simply providing an A.

Does D2L have a way for the instructor to access my submission while it appears "unread"?

Should I address this? If yes, with whom?

Comment: What would you like to happen? Does the prof have any other inputs to grading? Class participation...? Is it possible that the prof just wants some of the work done for the experience, rather than for grading?

Comment: Why would it ever change to "unread"? Shouldn't it stay "read" forever once the file was read? This software sounds buggy.

Comment: « Read to unread » or did you mean « unread to read »?

Comment: I don't really understand your question or your concern. The phrasing indicates that some of the papers are changing status, at least. Have you gotten marks on papers you think are not being read? Is it impossible to just ask the prof? Non-confrontationally of course.

Comment: @Buffy I am seeing a grade posted for the individual paper, not a module or final grade.

Comment: One thought: I download students’ assignments and then read them outside of the official course site. I am not sure if my system would record these as “read” or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about D2L specifically, but some software can have issues with properly recording whether some has been read. It is possible for example with some systems that if someone has Javascript not enabled they may be able to  read a file without getting recorded as accessed.

That said, if this isn't happening, the best thing may be to talk to Department Chair, and ask them to keep your concern anonymous. This will help minimize the chance of blowback/retaliation to you since the individual will not know you were the one who complained.  It may also make sense for similar reasons to wait until the end of the semester before talking to the Chair.

Comment: There is no way, of course, to guarantee that you will remain anonymous. Once you speak to a superior it is in their hands, not yours.